# Delphi buttons - Different appearance in design time and runtime

Tags: delphi, button, delphi-10.1-berlin

Has anyone had this problem ? In design time the button's appearance is normal. However, at runtime it is with the appearance of Windows 98 button.

[image: Runtime picture]

[image: Design time picture]

OS - Windows 7 64bit
Delphi 10.1 Berlin

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This happens when your application does not specify comtl32 v6 in the application manifest.

Typically that manifest setting would be arranged in your [project settings](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/Application_Options). Look under *Application*. You should see that *Manifest File* is set to *Auto Generate*, and that the *Enable Runtime Themes* item is checked. That is the IDE project setting that gives you comctl32 v6.

There are other ways to specify comctl32 v6 in your manifest. You might be supplying a custom manifest, for instance. If that is the case then you'll need to dig into what is going wrong with your manifest.

Comment: **You're right, David**. Thanks so much. Problem solved... []'s.